# How to do sorting when I have null value in a list

Tags: java, c#, list, spring-boot, sorting

I'm new in Java but I'm trying convert C# to Java and here I face some problem regarding sorting.

Since I'm doing a 5 times loop at above to generate the result, so when my code first time come in here, the `result`will be something like `[5,2,3], [null], [null], [null], [null]`.

So I want to sort it become `result = [2,3,5], [null], [null], [null], [null]`. But then when I'm trying to do this, I'll hit `NullPointerException`. And I guess it is because my list contains null value.

Java Code:

```java
Arrays.sort(result); 
String resultSorting = Arrays.toString(result);
result[j] = String.join(",", resultSorting);
```

And if C# I can do in lambda:

```cs
var resultSorting = result[j].Split(',').OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
result[j] = string.Join(",", resultSorting);
```

So how to solve this in Java?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671826/how-to-handle-nulls-when-using-java-collection-sort

Comment: You can use Arrays.sort() with a Comparator as a second argument. Write a comparator that accepts null values and all should be fine.

Comment: @Ralf Renz, Thanks for comment. I have try this solution, but the sorting are not working and it will only accept null value. Since my list is `[5,2,3], [null], [null]` not `[2, null, null, 3, 5]`. So this is the problem I don't know how should I do...

Comment: Ok. But than you don't want to sort the array result but the elements of result. Make a loop over the array and decide by the content of each element if you sort it or not.

Comment: Sorry @RalfRenz, I not quite get it, Is there any example I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to solve my problem.

Before sort the element of the result, I do split the comma for my result element so that it will only do sorting for the element instead of whole array.

```
//Example of my result
result = [2,5,3], [null], [null], [null], [null];

String tempResult = result[j].replaceAll(",", ""); //After split the comma, result will become [253] instead of [2,5,3], [null], [null], [null], [null];
String[] resultSplitComma = tempResult.split("");
Arrays.sort(resultSplitComma);
String resultSorting = Arrays.toString(resultSplitComma);
result[j] = String.join(",", resultSorting);
```

And here I am very grateful to everyone who are trying to help me.

PS: This is the only solution I can think of at the moment. So if anyone still have any better solution, feel free to comment to let me learn more :)

Answer (score 1):

If it were a collection of java objects, you can implement the `Comparable` interface which is used to calculate the `.sort()` of the objects.

Luckily though, the Stream API already has some useful built in methods along with Comparator.

For your strings for example I've written this:

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Sort Array of Strings with Nulls First or Last")
void sorty(){

    final String[] unsortedArray = {"Bob",null,"Alice",null,"Charlie","Emma",null,null,"Dave"};

    //To List with Stream, Sort using Comparator but with nulls first then collect to String list.
    final List<String> sortedArray = Arrays.stream(unsortedArray)
                .sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareToIgnoreCase))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Assertions
    String[] expectedResult = {null,null,null,null,"Alice","Bob","Charlie","Dave","Emma"};
    Assertions.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(expectedResult),sortedArray);
    Assertions.assertNotEquals(Arrays.asList(unsortedArray),sortedArray);

    //Or using nullsLast:

    //To List with Stream, Sort using Comparator but with nulls last then collect to String list.
    final List<String> sortedArrayNullsLast = Arrays.stream(unsortedArray)
                .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(String::compareToIgnoreCase))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Assertions
    String[] expectedResultNullsLast = {"Alice","Bob","Charlie","Dave","Emma",null,null,null,null};
        Assertions.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(expectedResultNullsLast),sortedArrayNullsLast);
        Assertions.assertNotEquals(Arrays.asList(unsortedArray),sortedArrayNullsLast);
        
        
    //PS: You can instead of Collect to List of Strings in the Stream to an array instead...

    //To List with Stream, Sort using Comparator but with nulls last then collect to String list. I just did
    // to list to compare them in the assertion tests.
    final String[] sortedArrayNullsLastAsArray = Arrays.stream(unsortedArray)
                .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(String::compareToIgnoreCase))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
```

Comment: Will this work for my case? Because I array format is like `[3,2,5], [null], [null]` instead of `[2, null , 3, null, null, 5]`

Comment: Means that actually I would like to sort the element of the result, instead of the array. Because I have been try some Comparator build in mehthod and it will only ignore the null value but not working to sort the element.

Comment: Sort the element of the result?
In the case of `[1,9,4], [null], [3,2,5], [null], [null]` what result would you expect?

Comment: `[1,4,9], [null], [2,3,5], [null], [null]`. This is the result I expect.